# Django Rest Framework JSON serializer field failing validation with required=False and no default?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I set required to be false for a django rest framework JSON serializer field? It seems to be enforcing validation regardless of the required flag:

serializer field

```
results = serializers.JSONField(required=False, label='Result')
```

model field

```
results = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
```

But when I submit the form with a blank input, I get:

```
"results": [
    "Value must be valid JSON."
],
```

I've also tried changing the model default to {} in both the model field and the serializer field, but have the same response.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Linovia for pointing out that "The required flag does mean that the serializer will not complain if that field isn't present"

After some digging, it looks like DRF is setting a default value of null on the input, which then is caught as invalid... How can I override this, as the serializer "default" attribute doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
 "results": null,
```

Comment: in models.textfield use null=true

Comment: @Darshan it is a bad idea you don't need null values in a `TextField`, `blank=True` is enough.

Comment: You don't need a default value like empty string, because `blank=True` do it for you. It is actually strange logic, why you need `JSONField` on top of `TextField`? you can always save `JSON` string in a plain text. If you use postgres and  want binary format then use `JSONField` in your model. But your code should work, can you add model and serializer in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, one way to successfully and quickly implement this is using the initial keyword on the serializer, which will save an empty dict to the model instance (ensure you have coupled this with a django JSONField in the model definition itself)

serializer:

```
results = serializers.JSONField(required=False, initial=dict)
```

model:

```
results = JSONField(default=dict)
```

The browsable api will render with {} as the initial value, which you may or may not choose to modify.

Answer (score 5):

The `required` flag does mean that the serializer will not complain if that field isn't present.
However, if it is present, it will follow the validation process. It doesn't mean at all that it will be discarded if it doesn't validate.

Comment: Sure, but how do I allow the field to be optional? It seems that setting required=False on a serializer.CharField (or omitting required altogether) allows me to submit the form without a value, but I cannot do the same for a serializer.JSONField?

Comment: You may change your question's title as it's misleading and update your question with more context. What you mentioned here totally changes the initial question.

Comment: I updated my answer earlier with more information. It looks like the default value attribute on JSON serializer fields has no effect, and instead set to null, which fails validation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the required flag, though I'm still not quite at the bottom of this!

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an issue with DRF's [empty](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L43) class (used "to represent no data being provided for a given input or output value). The empty value for a `JSONField` is not json serializable, so you see

```
"results": [
    "Value must be valid JSON."
],
```

To fix this, I overrode DRF's JSONField with my own NullableJSONField

```
from rest_framework.fields import empty

class NullableJSONField(serializers.JSONField):

    def get_value(self, dictionary):
        result = super().get_value(dictionary)
        if result is empty:
            return None
        return result
```

and added `allow_null=True` to the field in the serializer

```
json_blob = NullableJSONField(required=False, allow_null=True)
```

The issue with this fix is that the `json_blob` field is then serialized with `None` in the response. (e.g. `"json_blob": {}`)

I hope this resolves your issue, and I will post an update if I find a solution that complete removes this field from the response when it is not input.

Answer (score 0):

you can use syntax something like...

```
class DetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
results = ResultSerializer(

        allow_empty_file=True,required=False
    )
```